# Are there any ways to composite Sentinel-2 bands with python?

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2, osgeo

Sentinel-2 satellite bands have different spacial resolutions, so how can I composite bands of satellite image in python (instead of gdal_merge script)?
 I tried to stack them by numpy, write each raster in each output band by GDAL, resize and reshape rasters and stack them. All of them are not working. 
When I tried to stack bands in QGIS, it works perfectly, all bands are available.